# SQL to Calculate Customer Tenure/Service Start Date using a cooldown period logic

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

The business scenario here is to calculate the customer tenure with the service provider. Customer tenure is calculated based on below aspects:

- Oldest account start date to be taken for tenure calculation
- One Customer can have more than 1 active account at a given time
- Cooldown period is 6 months, i.e., if a customer has to stay as a customer, s/he has 6 months to open a new account with the provider after closing the account or should already have another account open before closing
- If the customer opens an account post 6 months then the tenure calculation happens from the new account open date

We can better understand this with an example: (values in bold are Customer since/tenure-start date)

| Customer_ID | ACCT_SERIAL_NUM | ACCT_STRT_DT | ACCT_END_DT | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | Account1 | **2000-01-20** | (null) | Customer already had an active account before closing the existing account |
| 11111 | Account2 | 2002-12-10 | 2021-09-22 |  |
| 11111 | Account3 | 2021-10-22 | (null) |  |

| Customer_ID | ACCT_SERIAL_NUM | ACCT_STRT_DT | ACCT_END_DT | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11112 | Account1 | **2000-01-20** | 2002-08-10 | Account closed but customer opened another account within cooling period of 6months |
| 11112 | Account2 | 2002-12-10 | 2021-09-22 |  |
| 11112 | Account3 | 2021-10-22 | (null) |  |

| Customer_ID | ACCT_SERIAL_NUM | ACCT_STRT_DT | ACCT_END_DT | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11113 | Account1 | 2000-01-20 | 2002-05-10 | Account closed but customer didn't open another account within cooling period of 6months |
| 11113 | Account2 | **2002-12-10** | 2021-09-22 | Hence this is the new customer tenure start date |
| 11113 | Account3 | 2021-10-22 | (null) |  |

**The query I was trying (below) could possibly help me if the events occur sequentially** (like in above 3 scenarios)

```
With dataset as (
    SELECT Customer_ID, ACCT_SERIAL_NUM, ACCT_STRT_DT, ACCT_END_DT, COMMENTS, 
    CASE WHEN NVL(LEAD(ACCT_STRT_DT, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY ACCT_STRT_DT asc ) , SYSDATE-1 ) < ADD_MONTHS(nvl(acct_end_dt, SYSDATE), 6) 
        THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as ACTV_FLG 
    FROM calc_customer_tenure ct
order by Customer_ID, ACCT_STRT_DT asc )
SELECT 
Customer_ID, MIN(CASE WHEN FLAG = 'Y' THEN ACCT_STRT_DT ELSE NULL END) as CUST_TNUR 
FROM (
    SELECT ds.*, 
        CASE WHEN ACCT_END_DT is NULL 
        THEN 'Y' ELSE MIN(ACTV_FLG) OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_ID ORDER BY ACCT_STRT_DT asc ROWS between current row and unbounded following) 
        END as FLAG
    from dataset ds )
GROUP BY Customer_ID ORDER BY Customer_ID ;
```

**but fails for the below scenario: (which is an ideal real-world scenario)**

Unfortunately the above code takes account3 as start date instead of taking account1:

| Customer_ID | ACCT_SERIAL_NUM | ACCT_STRT_DT | ACCT_END_DT | COMMENTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11114 | Account1 | **2000-01-20** | 2021-08-22 | Customer has closed this account(1) after subsequent account(2) is closed. But then has opened an account(3) within 6 months of closing the account(1) hence this is the tenure start date |
| 11114 | Account2 | 2002-12-10 | 2003-12-10 |  |
| 11114 | Account3 | 2021-10-22 | (null) |  |

Comment: Provide sample data according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), "5. Some Additional Suggestions".

Comment: *The query I was trying (below)* You use oracleDB syntax. Does the question is tagged with [mysql] mistakenly?

Comment: That's true, since I am comfortable with Oracle hence the syntax. But we can also use MySQL if required. Just trying to understand the logic/approach to the problem. 
For sample (on MySQL), here is the DB-Fiddle link (https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/igM69vKw2RGWSLoPmAjf1k/5)

Comment: Look at this: https://dbfiddle.uk/DTiDmWAu The data from the last line (rn = max) allows to identify the row where the tenure starts.

Comment: Thanks a Bunch @Akina! That query helped - I did few modifications on top of it to run in oracle and was able to get the desired output! Will let know if in case any scenario fails in future.

Answer (score 1):

**Thanks to [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina) I was able to re-write the query to fit as required! Also thanks to [P3Consulting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956336/p3consulting) for contributing!** Really appreciate the support!

---

Re-posting the final SQL here for the Oracle which helped with my use case:

**Below is using Recursive CTEs**

```
WITH cte1 as (
  SELECT customer_id, ACCT_STRT_DT, ACCT_END_DT,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY ACCT_STRT_DT) rn
  FROM calc_customer_tenure
), cte2 (customer_id, ACCT_STRT_DT, ACCT_END_DT, rn, tenure_start_date, tenure_end_date) AS (
  SELECT customer_id, ACCT_STRT_DT, ACCT_END_DT, rn, 
        ACCT_STRT_DT tenure_start_date,
        ACCT_END_DT tenure_end_date
  FROM cte1
  WHERE rn = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT cte1.customer_id, cte1.ACCT_STRT_DT, cte1.ACCT_END_DT, cte1.rn,
         CASE WHEN cte1.ACCT_STRT_DT > ADD_MONTHS(cte2.tenure_end_date, 6)
              THEN cte1.ACCT_STRT_DT
              ELSE cte2.tenure_start_date
              END,
         CASE WHEN cte1.ACCT_STRT_DT > ADD_MONTHS(cte2.tenure_end_date, 6)
              THEN cte1.ACCT_END_DT
              ELSE GREATEST(cte1.ACCT_END_DT, cte2.tenure_end_date)
              END  
  FROM cte1
  JOIN cte2 ON cte1.customer_id = cte2.customer_id AND cte1.rn = cte2.rn + 1 
)
SELECT customer_id, CASE WHEN ADD_MONTHS(NVL(tenure_end_date, SYSDATE), 6) < SYSDATE THEN NULL ELSE tenure_start_date END AS CUSTOMER_TENURE_START_DATE FROM (
SELECT 
  cte2.*, row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by rn desc) as rank_derv
  FROM cte2 ) subset
  WHERE rank_derv = 1 
  ORDER BY 1,2 ;
```

> I am also posting one which may work in case of Oracle only (since it uses hierarchical query syntax):

```
WITH dataset_rnkd as (
SELECT CT.*, row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by ACCT_STRT_DT DESC)  as row_rnk
from calc_customer_tenure  CT 
) 
SELECT customer_id, MIN(ACCT_STRT_DT) as CUSTOMER_TENURE FROM (
SELECT * FROM dataset_rnkd
START WITH ADD_MONTHS(NVL(ACCT_END_DT, SYSDATE), 6) >= SYSDATE
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR customer_id = customer_id AND PRIOR ACCT_STRT_DT <= ADD_MONTHS(NVL(ACCT_END_DT, SYSDATE), 6) 
) DS 
GROUP BY customer_id 
ORDER BY customer_id ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, gives the correct results for the dataset you supplied, but you should test more scenarii:

```
with data(customer_id,acct_serial_num,acct_strt_dt,acct_end_dt,comments) as
(
select '11111', 'Account1', to_date('2000-01-20','yyyy-mm-dd'), cast(NULL AS DATE), 'Customer already had an active account before closing the existing account' from dual union all
select '11111', 'Account2', to_date('2002-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2021-09-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), '' from dual union all  
select '11111', 'Account3', to_date('2021-10-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), cast(NULL AS DATE), '' from dual union all

select '11112', 'Account1', to_date('2000-01-20','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2002-08-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Account closed but customer opened another account within cooling period of 6months' from dual union all
select '11112', 'Account2', to_date('2002-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2021-09-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), '' from dual union all  
select '11112', 'Account3', to_date('2021-10-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), cast(NULL AS DATE), '' from dual union all

select '11113', 'Account1', to_date('2000-01-20','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2002-05-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Account closed but customer didn''t open another account within cooling period of 6months' from dual union all
select '11113', 'Account2', to_date('2002-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2021-09-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Hence this is the new customer tenure start date' from dual union all
select '11113', 'Account3', to_date('2021-10-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), cast(NULL AS DATE), '' from dual union all

select '11114', 'Account1', to_date('2000-01-20','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2021-08-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), 'Customer has closed this account(1) after subsequent account(2) is closed. But then has opened an account(3) within 6 months of closing the account(1) hence this is the tenure start date' from dual union all
select '11114', 'Account2', to_date('2002-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2003-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), '' from dual union all  
select '11114', 'Account3', to_date('2021-10-22','yyyy-mm-dd'), cast(NULL AS DATE), '' from dual    
),
datawc as (
    select d.customer_id,acct_serial_num,acct_strt_dt, nvl(d.acct_end_dt, to_date('2999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd')) as acct_end_dt, 
        nvl(add_months(acct_end_dt,6),to_date('2999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd')) as cooldown_end_dt, 
        case when 
            acct_strt_dt < add_months(lag(acct_end_dt,1) over(partition by customer_id order by acct_strt_dt),6) 
            then 1 else 0 end as prev_within_cooldown,
        case when 
            add_months(nvl(acct_end_dt, to_date('2999-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd')),6) > lead(acct_strt_dt,1) over(partition by customer_id order by acct_strt_dt)
            then 1 else 0 end as next_within_cooldown,
        d.comments
    from data d
),
mergeddata as (
    select customer_id, acct_serial_num, acct_strt_dt, acct_end_dt, prev_within_cooldown, next_within_cooldown, cooldown_end_dt, comments
    from datawc d
    match_recognize(
        partition by customer_id
        order by acct_strt_dt,acct_end_dt
        measures first(acct_serial_num) as acct_serial_num, cooldown_end_dt as cooldown_end_dt, 
            first(prev_within_cooldown) as prev_within_cooldown, first(next_within_cooldown) as next_within_cooldown,
            comments as comments, first(acct_strt_dt) as acct_strt_dt, max(acct_end_dt) as acct_end_dt
        pattern( merged* str)
        define merged as acct_end_dt >= next(acct_strt_dt)
    )
)
select d.customer_id, min(acct_strt_dt) as tenure_dt
from mergeddata d
where next_within_cooldown = 1
group by d.customer_id
;

CUSTO TENURE_DT  
----- -----------
11111 20-JAN-2000
11112 20-JAN-2000
11113 10-DEC-2002
11114 20-JAN-2000
```